# User login fails if redirect to pages other than home page after login in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on a Yii2 advance application i have created different user models and different loginForm classes for both `frontend` and `backend` in common folder.

The problem is that i want to redirect to links other that home page after login in frontend but when i redirect then to pages other than home page user login fails. i.e., i don't get anything in `Yii::$app->user->id`.

if I print `Yii::$app->user->id` just after `if($model->login)` before redirection than i get user data. but after redirection that data is lost.

if i redirect to home page then after login `return $this->home()` then i am getting user data in session. but i don't get data if i redirect to any page other than home page.

I am not able to find the issue here. what could be the solution.

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same (sub-)domain you are logging in on?

Comment: Yes same domain.. there is no sub-domain